Where can I ask questions about Windows 11 as an user?
As this site seems to not be the good place for my question(s), I won't go into much details for the moment. I have just bought and used a few days a computer that has Windows 11 Pro (64 bit) as operating system installed. (Not by myself, because it's second hand.) I indicate just the following so that you see the kind of questions I am interested to ask.
When I want to save a file after editing it (e.g. an OpenOffice table file) it seems to never accept saving without making a new file - this is apparently the case with (nearly?) all files that I created on my old computer with Windows 10 and have taken over (via DVD) to my new computer. Is this a bug? (There has already been another weird behavior of Win 11 which I saw and diappeared after an automatic update of Windows!) In case it is not, where does this problem come from?
The place to ask my questions on Win 11 as an user might be another site in StackExchange or anywhere else in the web.

edit this question to only include your problems with editing/saving files, add a screenshot of a few file properties and flag it to the moderator to request for migration to SuperUser site
